# Android Gridlayout :how to change the height of each row?

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

In **GridLayout** i want to stretch the button height in row (ie to take 3 rows or more ) i could to specify the height (1 or 2 rows) using the command          **android:layout_rowSpan="2"** but its not working when is set the attribute  **android:layout_rowSpan**  to 3 or 4 . any help ?

in the below screen shoot i want to change the height of button 3 to take three rows

[image]

**There is my code :**

```
    <GridLayout android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="6"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="Button 1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="Button 2"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="3"
    android:text="Button 3"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="Button 4"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: For that, you should not choose gridview. You should use RecyclerView. It allows to create grid with different size of row/columns. http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/

Comment: @SujithNiraikulathan No gridview will not give me complex design in all items height and width

Comment: That is why I am telling you to use RecyclerView. You checked the link I shared in the previous comment?